# Accessing pointer parameter values from a C++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I have this C++ dll with the following function:

```
extern "C" INT16 WINAPI SetWatchElements(INT16 *WatchElements)
{
INT16 Counter;

//some code

for (Counter = 0; Counter < WATCHSIZE; Counter++)
    WatchElements[Counter] = MAPINT(WatchData[Counter]);

//some code

return ReturnValue;
}
```

Essentially it just assigns some values to the pointer/array that is passed in.

My problem arises when I attempt to call this function via C#.  Here is the function definition in C#:

```
[DLLImport("MyDll.dll")]
private static extern int SetWatchElements(ref Int16 watchElements);
```

and how I am calling it:

```
Int16 someData = 0;
var result = SetWatchElements(ref someData);
```

This compiles fine and my variable `someData` actually has a value in it that is right.  The problem is that since in C++ world the values are set beyond the realm of a single value so I am unsure how to access that in C#.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
Int16[] someData = new Int16[80];
var result = SetWatchElements(ref someData[0]);
```

but the result is the same.

PS: I CANNOT use unsafe here as it is against our standards.

Comment: `SetWatchElements(ref someData[0]);` should have worked out ok as long as you are not crossing process boundaries.... do you have some evidence that it failed?

Comment: I displayed all the values in a console window and someData[0] had a value in it, but all other indices were 0

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare the imported function as:

```
[DLLImport("MyDll.dll")]
private static extern int SetWatchElements(Int16[] watchElements);
```

And call it without `ref`:

```
Int16[] someData = new Int16[80];
var result = SetWatchElements(someData);
```

Comment: This worked, but it didn't ha.  I have a Forms application and a console application that both use the same dll.  This worked for the console application, but the forms application returned the dll's error response code.  I have the dll function definitions defined in the form file.  Do you know if there is any reason that would cause different behavior?

Comment: @Josh Make sure that both applications have the same target platform (x86, x64).

Comment: I did, they are both (x86).  The forms application is hit or miss.  Sometimes the function call goes through sometimes it doesn't.  I've tried putting the methods in a background thread, but same result.  The c++ dll is used to communicate to a serial interface, so I don't know if there is some issue with forms syncing to a serial interface or what.